# How to create branching results for @ResponseStatus

Tags: java, spring

Using @ResponseStatus allows setting the status of a Rest response in Spring. But how could this be used for different kinds of status that could come from the same request?

For example, there is a method in the controller that may return a 200 or a 404. How could I define these statuses just using @ResponseStatus in one method?

Comment: Please refer https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-status for a good explanation around its usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you wouldn't do this with `@ResponseStatus`.  Instead, you can use `ResponseEntity<...>` as the return type of your method.  If the 'type' of returned item can change, `ResponseEntity<?>` or `ResponseEntity<Object>` works too.

For example:

```
@GetMapping("/{key}")
public ResponseEntity<Thing> getThing(final @PathVariable String key) {
    final Thing theThing = this.thingService.get(key);

    final ResponseEntity<?> response;
    if (theThing.someProperty()) {
         response = ResponseEntity.ok(theThing);
    } else {
         response = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_MODIFIED).body(null);
    }

    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question directly, `@ResponseStatus` **cannot** be used to send different statuses by a single method.

If you *want* to use `@ResponseStatus`, how you can handle multiple statuses is:

- Have the controller method annotated with `@ResponseStatus` with the required **2xx** `HttpStatus`. This status would be sent by the controller method in the success scenario. Usually it is used to set `HttpStatus` other than **200** (like **201**), as **200** is the default status sent even without using `@ResponseStatus`.
- Have exception handler methods annotated with `@ExceptionHandler`, to handle different exception scenarios, also annotated with `@ResponseStatus` with the corresponding `HttpStatus`. For eg if you want to handle a *Resource not found* scenario, the exception handler method can be annotated with `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)` to send back a **404**.
- In case you don't need to send a dynamic error response, you can even mark the custom exception class with `@ResponseStatus` along with the required `HttpStatus`, and when the exception is thrown (and not caught and swallowed explicitly), the corresponding `HttpStatus` would be returned.

You can even leverage `ResponseEntity` which has a `status` method where you can pass the required `HttpStatus` and return, either in the controller method or in the exception handler method as below:

**Controller method:**

```
@GetMapping("/resource")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getResource(){
        if(resourcePresent){
            return new ResponseEntity(resource, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
}
```

**Exception handler method:**

```
    @ExceptionHandler(BadRequestException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleBadRequestException(BadRequestException exception){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(customResponse, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use @ResponseStatus to set a different status code from one method depending on branching results.

You will have to return a ResponseEntity or manipulate the HttpServletResponse directly in your method (or eventually throw exceptions in error cases with exception handlers returning the status)

Comment: This is not entirely true if I get what you mean, if used with `@ControllerAdvice` or `@ExceptionHandler` that is exactly what you can do.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is gonna answer your question but you could throw a `ResponseStatusException` with the status code you need. Using it for the 200 would be strange though.

Comment: * Using it for any non-exceptional case would be strange.

Comment: @user2478398 yes, exactly what I said. But actually also using `@ResponseStatus` to set a 200 would be overkill in my opinion. The 200 is gonna be returned by the normal flow of the method.